can't seem to increase the memory limit
FYI, I'm a designer and don't have mutch experience in this field. I bareley understand what i am doing atm.
I need to increase the memory limit of a wordpress site to use a plugin. It's curently at 128M but it needs to be 256M.
I edited the php.ini and wp_config file without succes. I don't have the rights to acces the server via FTP at the moment. i want to see where the instalation gets the memory limit from but i don't know how.
I have tried some of the advice on here. I believe the awnser is already somewhere on here, i just lack the experience to apply it. does anyone have an advice for me?

I edited the php.ini and wp_config file I'm a  little confused. If you dont have access to the server what did you edit?
